# free .NET translation libraries

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a .net C# library that can do translations. I tried googles one but they charge money now for it.

I am looking for something that can preferably auto detect languages, translate blocks of text or download the entire page and convert it.

This all has to of course be done through code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using bing?

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/

There is a translator .net library on codeplex that uses bing: http://translateit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I never tired it but it does not support the languages I will need(Chinese,Korean,Japanese)

Comment: Uh? All the languages you list are supported.

Comment: Translate !t currently supports following languages to translate from
1. English
2. German
3. French
4. Spanish